# Why strcmp() returning '0' though I am not providing null terminated string?

Tags: c

In the below code I was expecting some weird behavior(like infinite loop) as I am not providing null terminated string as an input to strcmp() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
  char string1[20];
  char string2[20] = {'H','e','l','l','o',};

  strcpy(string1, "Hello");
 // strcpy(string2, "Hellooo");
  printf("Return Value is : %d\n", strcmp( string1, string2));

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
 Return Value is : 0
```

Why it is showing me both strings are equal?

My guess is when I initialized array (string2)rest elements are filled with zero.But as the array is  local this should not be the case.

Comment: your guess is correct.

Comment: You are correct, rest of the array will be initialized to 0. For example, the common way to initialize an array is `char temp[100] = {0}`. Here, you are just providing the first member of array but if you look at the memory layout for `temp`, you will see that all the array has been filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an initialiser to an array or struct only provides data for parts of the array or struct , the rest of the array or struct is set to `0`. This is the case for `string2`.

Comment: There's an exception to this: if an array is initialized from a string literal then the characters after the null-terminator are indeterminate (ref. C99 6.7.8#14; cf. #21 which only applies to brace-enclosed list)

Answer (score 5):

I dumped the `string2` and I got

```
72 101 108 108 111 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The rest of the `string2` is filled with `0`s

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    printf("%d ", string2[i]);
```

And when I did this, I got

```
char string2[20];

string2[0] = 'H';
string2[1] = 'e';
string2[2] = 'l';
string2[3] = 'l';
string2[4] = 'o';

72 101 108 108 111 127 0 0 -27 5 64 0 0 0 0 0 -1 -78 -16 0 Return Value is : 127
```

When you initialize the string in the definition part, the rest of the string is filled with `0`s.

But, when you just define it and then assign values to them, it is filled with *junk* values

Comment: Dumping the value of `string2` and seeing the trailing zeros suggests, but does not strongly prove that `char string2[20] = {'H','e','l','l','o',};` did that zero filling.  One would also need to see the prior values of memory for `string2` before its definition - a tricky thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

`Partially initialised` array will filled or initiaslised with Zeroes of remaining uninitialised memory

e.g

```
int a[10]={1,2,3}
```

remaining index will be filled (initialised)with zeros(0)

Answer (score 2):

As already everybody has enlightened you with the correct answer. This example is to make it more clear::

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
 char temp[100] = {'A'} ;
 return 0 ;
}
```

The disassembly for array initializing part is::

```
//char temp[100] = {'A'} ;
// 41h is 'A', so this instruction fills the first index with 'A'
mov         byte ptr [ebp-6Ch],41h 
push        63h  
push        0    
lea         eax,[ebp-6Bh] 
push        eax 

// Then it calls memset which in turn fills the rest of array with zeroes.
call        @ILT+115(_memset) (0B11078h) 
add         esp,0Ch
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether the scope of `string2` array is global or local, it will be initialized to zero, in this case.

The only difference you will observe is when you declare `string2` locally and do not initialize it at all, i.e. `char string2[20];`.

Doing this way locally allocates `string2` on stack and no explicit initilaization takes place, but if you do the same globally the array will be initialized to zero (all indices).

Therefore, your guess is partially correct!!

Answer (score 1):

> C11 (n1570), §7.24.2.3 The **strcpy** function
>
> The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (**including
>   the terminating null character**) into the array pointed to by s1.

The first 6 elements in your string1 and string2 become the same. Terminator is also at the same position.

Comment: I think the question was why string2 is also null terminated.

Comment: Seems I got the wrong idea. He could have just used `char string1[20] = "Hello";` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: @Griddoor Note: `char string1[20] = "Hello";` does not initialize  `string1[6]` to `string1[19]` like `char string2[20] = {'H','e','l','l','o',};` does.

Comment: @chux: Yes they are different. Though if the question was "why string2 is null terminated", the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @Griddoor Right you are.